# $f(x, y, z):=\left(x+y^2+z^2, x-y+z, 2 x+y-z\right)$ local and global inverse, calculating $Df^{-1}$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse

> We consider the mapping $f: \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^3$ given by
> $$
> f(x, y, z):=\left(x+y^2+z^2, x-y+z, 2 x+y-z\right) .
> $$
> a) Show that $f$ has a local inverse around the point $(1,-1,2)$.
> b) Calculate $D f^{-1}(6,4,-1)$.
> c) Can the inverse be defined globally?

a) Do I need to calculate the derivative of the Jacobian matrix and show that it is not equal to zero? Is that enough?
$D f(1,-1,2)=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2(-1) & 2(2) \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & -2 & 4 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$ 
$Det(Df) = 6 \neq 0.$
b) I can find the inverse of the Jacobian matrix:
$D f(x, y, z)=\left[\begin{array}{lll}
\frac{\partial f_1}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_1}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial f_2}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_2}{\partial z} \\
\frac{\partial f_3}{\partial x} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial y} & \frac{\partial f_3}{\partial z}
\end{array}\right]=\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 2 y & 2 z \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]
$
So $D f(6,4,-1) =\left[\begin{array}{ccc}
1 & 8 & -2 \\
1 & -1 & 1 \\
2 & 1 & -1
\end{array}\right]$ and I need to find the inverse of the matrix so that I am finished.
c) I don'tt know how to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are correct for (a). You need to use the inverse function theorem to claim that, since $Df (1, -1, 2)$ is invertible, $f$ is locally invertible.

For (b), you are calculating $Df$, but the question asks you to calculate $Df^{-1}$. You seem to think that

$$Df^{-1} (x, y, z) = \text{inverse of } Df (x, y, z),$$

which is not true in general. Instead, one needs to find $Df^{-1}$ implicitly using chain rule: since $f^{-1}$ is defined by

$$ f \circ  f^{-1} (x, y, z) = (x, y, z),$$

differentiating on both sides at $(6, 4-1)$ and using chain rule gives

$$Df (f^{-1}(6, 4, -1) )\circ Df^{-1} (6, 4, -1) = I,$$

since $f^{-1} (6, 4, -1) = (1, -1, 2)$ and you have found $Df(1, -1, 2)$ in (a), the answer to (b) is the inverse of $Df(1, -1, 2)$.

(c) There is no general way to find an inverse of a function (unless it's a linear function). In your particular equation, when one sees terms like $y^2, z^2$, one would guess that $f$ is not injective (by plugging $y\mapsto -y$ or $z\mapsto -z$). It almost work if you choose $y=z$ (to get rid of $y-z$ in the second and third components). Thus one can see that

$$ f(x, t, t) = f(x, -t, -t)$$

for all $t\in \mathbb R$. Thus $f$ is not bijective and does not have a global inverse.

**Remark** The notation $f^{-1}$ is in general reserved for the (global) inverse of $f$, while in your question, $f^{-1}$ seems to refer to the local inverse of $f$ around $(1, -1, 2)$, which exists by (a).

Comment: how do you easily know that  $f^{-1} (6, 4, -1) = (1, -1, 2)$?

Comment: I just plug $(1, -1, 2)$ into $f$ and it's $f(1, -1, 2) = (6, 4, -1)$. @Allison

Comment: Thanks everything is completely clear! I totally understand it. When you have time,  could you maybe look at this question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4699861/determine-the-derivative-of-f-at-a-in-mathbbrn-and-the-second-order-der as well ?